# Laravel testing with with codeception: unit test model's save() method doesn't persist

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, codeception

It's a simple unit test to test DB persistence,cannot get it work. Keeps on getting below error message.

Looks like the save() method can not insert record to testdb, I change assertion with existing records in the testing db, it works.

$this->tester->seeInDatabase('statuses', ['name' => 'Status4']);

Spent hours on troubleshooting, got no clue.

Thanks,
Jack

```
    There was 1 failure:

    ---------
    1) UserTest: Saving status
     Test  tests\unit\App\UserTest.php:testSavingStatus
    No matching records found for criteria {"name":"Status4"} in table statuses
    Failed asserting that 0 is greater than 0.
    #1  Codeception\Module\Db->seeInDatabase
    #2  C:\MAMP\htdocs\noc\tests\_support\_generated\UnitTesterActions.php:3725
    #3  C:\MAMP\htdocs\noc\tests\unit\App\UserTest.php:34
    #4  App\UserTest->testSavingStatus  

    public function testSavingStatus()
        {
            $status = new Status();
            $status->setName('Status4');
            $status->save();

            $this->assertEquals('Status4', $status->name);
            $this->tester->seeInDatabase('statuses', ['name' => 'Status4']);
        }

   actor: Tester
    paths:
        tests: tests
        log: tests/_output
        data: tests/_data
        support: tests/_support
        envs: tests/_envs
    settings:
        bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
        colors: false
        memory_limit: 1024M
    extensions:
        enabled:
            - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
    modules:
        config:
            Db:
                dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb'
                user: 'root'
                password: 'root'
                dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
                populate: true
                cleanup: false
                reconnect: true
```

Comment: Do you use Laravel module? If you do, try to use seeRecord method http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5#seeRecord

Comment: I can try that later, but doesn't look like the record had been inserted. Seeindatabase works for existing records.

Answer (score 0):

Db module can't see the record because it uses a separate connection and Laravel5 module wraps test [in transaction](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5#Config):

> cleanup: boolean, default true - all database queries will be run in a transaction, which will be rolled back at the end of each test.

Use [seeRecord](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5#seeRecord) method of Laravel5 module instead or disable cleanup if you have other reasons to use Db module.

Comment: Yes, seeInRecord saved my life, thanks a million. How do I disable cleanup if I want to use DB module?

Comment: You have to add `cleanup: false` option under Laravel5 module